# Save a struct with NSCoding

Tags: swift, struct, nscoder

I want to save the following data:

```
class Book: NSObject, NSCoding {

var title: String
var chapter: [Chapter]

struct Chapter {
    var chapTitle: String
    var texte: [Texte]
}

struct Texte {
    var description: String
    var texte: [String]
    var position: [Int]
    var hidden: [Int?]
}
```

I am currently using the NSCoder to save the Book class:

```
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("learn")


struct PropertyKey {
    static let title = "title"
    static let chapter = "Chapter"
}

//MARK: - Initialization
init?(title: String, chapter: [Book.Chapter]) {        
    self.title = title
    self.chapter = chapter
}

//MARK: - NSCoding
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(title, forKey: PropertyKey.title)
    aCoder.encode(chapter, forKey: PropertyKey.chapter)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { 
    let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.title) as! String
    let chapter = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.chapter) as! [Book.Chapter]

    self.init(title: title, chapter: chapter)
}
```

With this I can save the Book's `title`, and an empty array of `chapter`.

However when I try to add `chapTitle` and `texte` to a Book object, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[*SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000066dec0'*

Does this mean that the struct could not be saved ? What should I change ?

Comment: Why use the old `NSCoding` protocol, when you can use `Codable` in Swift 4?

Comment: You can’t since a struct it is not a class therefore it can’t inherit from NSObject

Comment: You have two options. Use a class instead of a struct or use Codable protocol if you want to use a struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use codable if you can make book a struct .

```
struct Book: Codable {

var title: String
var chapter: [Chapter]

struct Chapter:Codable {
    var chapTitle: String
    var texte: [Texte]
}

struct Texte:Codable {
    var description: String
    var texte: [String]
    var position: [Int]
    var hidden: [Int?]
}
```

**Save**

```
static func saveData (books: [Book]) throws
{
     let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(books)
     try encoded.write(to: ArchiveURL)
     print("Books saved")
}
```

**Retrive**

```
//retrive data from it's saved place
static func loadData() throws -> [Book]
{
     let data = try Data(contentsOf: ArchiveURL)
     return try JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: data)
}
```

Also edit the variables on top

```
let directory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/learn/"

let ArchiveURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: directory)
```

Comment: I tried to use Codable, but when I try to load the data from URL, it returns `nil`. Here is the code I used:   SAVE:
    `static func saveData (books: [Book]) {
        guard let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(books) else { return }
        //To user defaults or what ever you choose
        try? encoded.write(to: ArchiveURL)
        print("Books saved")
    }`

Comment: LOAD: 
    `static func loadData()  -> [Book]?{
        let data = ArchiveURL.absoluteURL.dataRepresentation
        let parsedData  = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Book].self, from: data)
        return parsedData
    }`

Comment: your load and save function are wrong , i included two them in the updated  answer ,  please test it .

Comment: Ignoring the error (`try?`) and loading data via `FileManager` is not a good suggestion. Make both functions `throw`, return a non-optional in the `load` function and load the data with `let data = try Data(contentsOf: directoryURL)` since you are dealing with an URL anyway.

Comment: @vadian: Correct. When I loaded the data with `let data = try Data(contentsOf: directoryURL)`, it worked perfectly. Also the `throw` functions allowed me to identify an error in my data saving.

Comment: @Sameh: Please reflect vadian 's comment, so that I can mark your answer as the solution. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Sameh I edited the answer to remove redundant code. The benefit of passing through the error is that you can omit the `do - catch` block.

Comment: @vadian Thanks .